# Winding number of closed curves

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

> Let $c_1,c_2$ be closed curves in $\mathbb C^{\times}$ and we define $c(t):=\frac{c_1(t)}{c_2(t)}$. Proof the following for the winding number $win(c,0)=win(c_1,0)-win(c_2,0)$.

I have no idea to solve this problem. I need some hints.

Comment: Write $c_1(t)=r_1(t)e^{i\theta_1(t)}$ and $c_2(t)=r_2(t)e^{i\theta_2(t)}$..

Comment: How do you define winding number? Via integrals or via arguments? (They are the same thing with different appearances, though.)

Comment: Yes, via integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer (following Martin R. hint):

$$win(c,0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_c\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1\frac{c'(t)}{c(t)}dt$$
Since $c(t)=\frac{c_1(t)}{c_2(t)}$ the derivative is $c'(t)=\frac{c_1'(t)}{c_2(t)}-\frac{c_1(t)\cdot c_2'(t)}{c_2^2(t)}$.
We get then:$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1\frac{c'(t)}{c(t)}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_0^1\frac{c_1'(t)}{c_2(t)\cdot c(t)}-\frac{c_1(t)\cdot c_2'(t)}{c_2^2(t)\cdot c(t)}dt\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_0^1\frac{c_1'(t)\cdot c_2(t)}{c_2(t)\cdot c_1(t)}-\frac{c_1(t)\cdot c_2'(t)\cdot c_2(t)}{c_2^2(t)\cdot c_1(t)}dt\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_0^1\frac{c_1'(t)}{c_1(t)}-\frac{c_2'(t)}{c_2(t)}dt\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{c_1'(t)}{c_1(t)}dt-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{c_2'(t)}{c_2(t)}dt$$$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_1} \frac{dz}{z}-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_2} \frac{dz}{z}$$$$=win(c_1,0)-win(c_2,0)$$

Comment: Or: $\log c(t) = \log c_1(t) - \log c_2(t)$ and then take the derivative. (That's why it is called "logarithmic derivative".)

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
 win(c, 0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_c \frac{dz}{z} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}
 \int_0^1 \frac{c'(t)}{c(t)} \, dt
$$
and analogously  for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

From $c(t) = \frac{c_1(t)}{c_2(t)}$ one can easily compute a relationship between the
"logarithmic derivatives"
$$
\frac{c'(t)}{c(t)} \, , \, \frac{c_1'(t)}{c_1(t)} \, , \, \frac{c_2'(t)}{c_2(t)}
$$
which leads to the intended formula.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Should I post the answer here, to complete the question.

Comment: @serge: I have posted an "incomplete" answer because you asked for a "hint". Of course you can post an additional "full" answer.